# How to get grandtotal (refunding amount) in credit memo transactional email

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail, creditmemo, refund

How can we include a variable in credit memo transactional emails in magento for including total amount refunded while generating credit memo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{{var creditmemo.grand_total}} helps to get grand total refunded in credit memo email template.